# Entrian Source Search for vs 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Currently Entrian Search doesn't work with visual studio 2012.. Does anyone know when are they planning to releasing an update? Are there any other similar plugins which would work with vs2012 at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entrian Source Search now supports Visual Studio 2012 - see http://entrian.com/blog/source-search-1-4-1-visual-studio-2012/